# Find the coordinates of a point on a circle given 2 points and an angle

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

I have a circle with $A$ as a center, $B$ and $C$ two points on the circle.
I have the coordinates of $A$ (the center) and $B$ (the point on the circle). How can I find the coordinates of $C$ (another point on the circle knowing that  $\angle BAC$ is $0.384$ rad (or $22^\circ$).
The Y axis is upside down (see picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vp4W.jpg)

So I have $(X_a, Y_a)$ and $(X_b, Y_b)$ and I need to find $(X_c, Y_c)$ respecting the given axis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the angle formed between line ($AC$) and the x-axis. The picture you provided shows point $B$ on the x-axis which is not necessarily the case. The x-distance from point $A$ would be $\text{radius}\times \sin(\text{angle})$. The y-distance from point $A$ would be $\text{radius}\times \cos(\text{angle})$